# Java and Cucumber how to reuse scenario multithread

Tags: java, multithreading, cucumber

I use java and cucumber and there is a step which is used over and over in all my scenario.
I understand I can reuse a scenario but I still have a problem if I do that.

Supposing the scenario  I want to reuse is:

> Given a user exists

the step def is

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfiguration.class) 
public class UserStepDef {

     User user;

     @ Given("^A user exists$")
     public void a_user_exists() {

         user = createUser();
     }
}
```

The step definition creates an instance of the user object and assign it to the field "user" which will be used later in the following steps.
The only way I can have access to that field is having an instance of the class that ran that step --> userStepDef.user. 
I want to reuse that step definition in different Feature files but because the class that contains "user" is a singleton I can't run the tests in parallel.

Is there a better way? Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, you won't be able to run two tests in parallel on the same JVM, as there will be a race condition on access to the User object.

Read [this tutorial on current cucumber tests and maven](https://opencredo.com/running-cucumber-jvm-tests-in-parallel/) for information on how to run cucumber tests in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want is not to run the scenarios in parallel but to share some data between different steps files. Is that so?

If the answer is yes, have a look at the dependency injection approach with Cucumber. This will allow you to share class instances among different java files.

Comment: Hi Eugene, I am already using dependency injection, what I want is to be able to run tests in parallel, allowing different scenario to use the same step definition  but without sharing data between different scenario.
For instance I have Scenario 1 and Scenario 2, they both have the step "Given an existing user", and I don't want code duplication, I'd like to define the step once only in my UserStepDefinition.java class. The data I create in there: the user instance should not be shared between the Scenario 1 and Scenario 2, each Scenario has its own user.